# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when accessing triplets of a Graph

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm playing a bit with GraphX and got stuck with an Exception I can't explain.

My code generates 10 random nodes on a graph (of type `Point`) and then connects some of them. The logic itself doesn't really matter (and actually doesn't have any meaning). I just wanted to build a somewhat connected graph and got this Exception. The code goes as follows:

```
import scala.util.Random
case class Point(x:Double, y:Double, z:Double)


val vertices = sc.parallelize( 
   (1 to 10).map(i => (i.toLong, Point(Random.nextInt(10), Random.nextInt(10), Random.nextInt(10)))) 
)

val tmpGroups = vertices.map(x => (Random.nextInt(5), x) )
val edges = tmpGroups.cartesian(tmpGroups)
   .filter{case(x,y) => x._2._1 != y._2._1}
   .filter{case(x,y) => Math.abs(x._1 - y._1) <= 1}
   .map{case(x,y) => Edge(x._2._1, y._2._1, 1.)}

val graph = Graph(vertices, edges)
```

So far everything works, and when I collect `vertices` and `edges` they look fine:

```
graph.vertices.collect.foreach(println)
=> (4,Point(6.0,7.0,7.0))
   (8,Point(6.0,0.0,5.0))
   (1,Point(8.0,4.0,7.0))
   ... 

graph.edges.collect.foreach(println)
=> Edge(1,2,1.0)
   Edge(2,1,1.0)
   Edge(1,3,1.0)
   ...
```

Their types are (as expected):

```
org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexRDD[Point]
org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD[Double]
```

But when I try to collect `triplets` I get the following error:

```
graph.triplets.collect
```

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 40431.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 40431.0 (TID 8029, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$afab7c86681139df3241c999f2dafc38$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:214)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$afab7c86681139df3241c999f2dafc38$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:219)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$afab7c86681139df3241c999f2dafc38$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:221)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$afab7c86681139df3241c999f2dafc38$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:223)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$afab7c86681139df3241c999f2dafc38$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:225)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3baf9f919752f0ab1f5a31ad94af9f4$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:227)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3baf9f919752f0ab1f5a31ad94af9f4$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:229)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3baf9f919752f0ab1f5a31ad94af9f4$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:231)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3baf9f919752f0ab1f5a31ad94af9f4$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:233)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3baf9f919752f0ab1f5a31ad94af9f4$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:235)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$b968e173293ba7cd5c79f2d1143fd$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:237)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$b968e173293ba7cd5c79f2d1143fd$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:239)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$b968e173293ba7cd5c79f2d1143fd$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:241)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$b968e173293ba7cd5c79f2d1143fd$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:243)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$b968e173293ba7cd5c79f2d1143fd$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:245)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$b968e173293ba7cd5c79f2d1143fd$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:247)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$17f9c57b34a761248de8af38492ff086$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:249)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$17f9c57b34a761248de8af38492ff086$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:251)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$17f9c57b34a761248de8af38492ff086$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:253)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$17f9c57b34a761248de8af38492ff086$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:255)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$17f9c57b34a761248de8af38492ff086$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:257)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$bec1ee5c9e2e4d5af247761bdfbc3b3$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:259)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$bec1ee5c9e2e4d5af247761bdfbc3b3$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:261)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$bec1ee5c9e2e4d5af247761bdfbc3b3$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:263)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$bec1ee5c9e2e4d5af247761bdfbc3b3$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:265)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$bec1ee5c9e2e4d5af247761bdfbc3b3$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:267)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:269)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:271)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:273)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:275)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$5acc5a6ce0af8ab20753597dcc84fc0$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:277)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:279)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:281)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:283)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:285)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:287)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$33d793dde4292884a4720419646f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:289)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:291)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:293)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:295)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:297)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$725d9ae18728ec9520b65ad133e3b55$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:299)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:301)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:303)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:305)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:307)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$3d99ae6e19b65c7f617b22f29b431fb$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:309)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:311)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:313)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:315)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:317)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$ad149dbdbd963d0c9dc9b1d6f07f5e$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:319)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:321)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:323)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:325)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:327)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$6e49527b15a75f3b188beeb1837a4f1$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:329)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:331)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:333)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:335)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:337)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$$$93297bcd59dca476dd569cf51abed168$$$$$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:339)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:341)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:343)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:345)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:347)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:349)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:351)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:353)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:355)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:357)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:359)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:361)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:363)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:365)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:367)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:369)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:371)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:373)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:375)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:377)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:379)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:381)
    at $iwC$$iwC.(:383)
    at $iwC.(:385)
    at (:387)
    at .(:391)
    at .()
    at .(:7)
    at .()
    at $print()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:810)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:753)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:746)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:341)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

I can only guess the `$iwC` stuff are the anonymous functions in my code (`filter` and `map`). I've tried to test them separately and collect with/without some of them and nothing led me to a solution.

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT:**

I got it to work, but now it's even weirder...

If I collect and re-parallelize the `edges` RDD, it seems to work fine:

```
val graph = Graph(vertices, sc.parallelize(edges.collect))
graph.triplets.collect.foreach(println)
=> ((2,Point(5.0,9.0,0.0)),(3,Point(3.0,7.0,8.0)),1.0)
   ((2,Point(5.0,9.0,0.0)),(4,Point(2.0,5.0,4.0)),1.0)
   ((2,Point(5.0,9.0,0.0)),(5,Point(0.0,3.0,3.0)),1.0)
   ...
```

Can someone please explain this? I don't like voodoos...
What happens on re-parallelization? I guess partitions may change? Does that have anything to do with the original problem?

Comment: I'm guessing it's spark's laziness along with the usage of Random that bites you: since `tmpGroups` and `edges` aren't cached and are accessed twice, the `map` operation that is used to create it creates random values more than once, ending up with different values. Try adding `.cache()` at the end of the line that creates `tmpGroups` - might resolve the issue by caching the result created once and reusing it on all invocations.

Comment: @TzachZohar - You are probably right. When I cache tmpGroups or edges it indeed work and your explanation makes sense. Collecting and re-parallelizing, like in my update does practically the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Actually - add this as an answer if you want. I'll approve. It might help others who don't always read comments...

Comment: Sure - done. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Spark's *laziness* along with the usage of *Random* that bites you:

Since `tmpGroups` and `edges` aren't cached and are accessed twice, the `map` operation that is used to create them creates random values more than once, ending up with **different values** each time.

One way to solve this (more elegant usable than collecting and parallelizing again) is **caching**. By adding `.cache()` at the end of the line that creates `tmpGroups`, the result will be created exactly once:

```
val tmpGroups = vertices.map(x => (Random.nextInt(5), x) ).cache()
```